# How to use gaesessions in google-app-engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, session

I'm new to Python (as well as GAE), I'm trying to include gaesessions in my application, this is exactly what I did:

I copied the gaesessions folder to my src folder (the folder includes `__init__.py` file)

and added this to my working code:

```
from gaesessions import get_current_session

session = get_current_session()
```

I received the following error:

> `Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Program
>   Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\runtime\wsgi.py", line
>   174, in Handle
>       result = handler(self._environ, self._StartResponse)`
>
> `File "C:\Program
>   Files\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2\webapp2.py", line 1519, in
>   __call__
>       response = self._internal_error(e)`
>
> `File "C:\Program
>   Files\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2\webapp2.py", line 1511, in
>   __call__
>       rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)`
>
> `File "C:\Program
>   Files\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2\webapp2.py", line 1505, in
>   __call__
>       rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)`
>
> `File "C:\Program
>   Files\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2\webapp2.py", line 1253, in
>   default_dispatcher
>       return route.handler_adapter(request, response)`
>
> `File "C:\Program
>   Files\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2\webapp2.py", line 1077, in
>   __call__
>       return handler.dispatch()`
>
> `File "C:\Program
>   Files\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2\webapp2.py", line 547, in
>   dispatch
>       return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)`
>
> `File "C:\Program
>   Files\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2\webapp2.py", line 545, in
>   dispatch
>       return method(*args, **kwargs)`
>
> `File "D:....\src\helloworld.py", line 13, in get
>       session = get_current_session()`
>
> `File "D:....\src\gaesessions\__init__.py", line 36, in
>   get_current_session
>       return _tls.current_session`
>
> `File "C:\Python27\lib\_threading_local.py", line 193, in
>   __getattribute__
>       return object.__getattribute__(self, name)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've omitted the actual exception from your stack trace, but I'm guessing it's this:

> AttributeError: 'local' object has no attribute 'current_session'

If so, you've most likely skipped the [middleware configuration](https://github.com/dound/gae-sessions#readme) step. Create an `appengine_config.py` per the instructions and restart the dev server; this should resolve your error.

Comment: I found the same problem, but i already configured middleware.

Comment: yeah, this worked for me....!, But how do I configure the application by moving the file appengine_config.py in folder gaesession so the code looks like organized?