# GAESessions (Python) - "AttributeError: 'thread._local' object has no attribute 'current_session'."

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7

So I've been trying to implement the Janrain Engage plugin to the application I'm working on (Google App Engine (Python 2.7)), using GAESessions as the sessions library.

Following the instructions given on the [GAESessions page](https://github.com/dound/gae-sessions#readme), I created the "gaesessions" folder (containing "__init__.py") as well as "appengine_config.py" in my application's root directory, as well as the relevant files to process the plugin.

Attempting to login via Janrain, however, threw me a 500 error and gave me this traceback in the GAE logs:

```
E 2013-03-25 07:06:55.535

'thread._local' object has no attribute 'current_session'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.1/webapp2.py", line 1536, in __call__
    rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)
  File "/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.1/webapp2.py", line 1530, in __call__
    rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
  File "/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.1/webapp2.py", line 1278, in default_dispatcher
    return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
  File "/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.1/webapp2.py", line 1102, in __call__
    return handler.dispatch()
  File "/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.1/webapp2.py", line 572, in dispatch
    return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)
  File "/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.1/webapp2.py", line 570, in dispatch
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~k-sketch-test/10.366190612177083948/rpx.py", line 56, in post
    session = get_current_session()
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~k-sketch-test/10.366190612177083948/gaesessions/__init__.py", line 38, in get_current_session
    return _tls.current_session
AttributeError: 'thread._local' object has no attribute 'current_session'
```

I have searched through the [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15489106/gaesessions-cant-find-current-session-attribute) [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8095426/how-to-use-gaesessions-in-google-app-engine) regarding the "get_current_session()" issue, but they seem to be referencing 'local' instead of 'thread._local'.

Any ideas on what's going on here? Thanks in advance!

========

**{root folder}/appengine_config.py**

```
from gaesessions import SessionMiddleware

import os
COOKIE_KEY = '<hidden - was generated through os.urandom(64)>'

def webapp_add_wsgi_middleware(app):
  from google.appengine.ext.appstats import recording
  app = SessionMiddleware(app, cookie_key=COOKIE_KEY)
  app = recording.appstats_wsgi_middleware(app)
  return app
```

========

Answer (score 1):

**{root folder}/appengine_config.py** Is the file appengine_config.py in the root location?

```
aaps/app.yaml
    /main.py
    /appengine_config.py
    /gaesessions #folder
```

Can look a [basic tutorial on gaesessions](http://blog.stannard.net.au/2011/01/09/how-to-use-sessions-on-google-app-engine-with-python-and-gae-sessions/)